# Scrape website data, insert into an Excel cell, then move on to next

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, innertext

My project is to insert a car reg into the tax and mot website click the buttons, load the page and then take the dates.

An issue I had it is to extract data within a strong li element which is the date/ dates for the tax and mot of which I need in two cells.

```
Sub searchbot()

'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser

    Dim liEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <li> (link) element
    Dim pEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element

    Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'open internet

    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'open tax/mot page

    'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
    objIE.Navigate "https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/"

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'enter details in to page

    'in the search box put cell "b2" value, the word "in" and cell "C" value
    objIE.Document.getElementById("Vrm").Value = _
    Sheets("INPUT & DATA RESULTS").Range("F3").Value

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'click the 'Continue' button
objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'click the 'Yes' button
objIE.Document.getElementById("Correct_True").Click

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'click the 'Continue' button
objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'above works
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'HELP FROM HERE PLEASE

'take tax and mot dates and insert in to cells next to each other
'the first search result will go in row 2
y = 2

'TAKE TAX EXPIRY DATE AND PUT IN CELL
'I have tried reading up on extracting data from li elements, parent and child elements but struggling
For Each itemEle In objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top-section-list")
data = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("li")(0).innerText


'TAKE MOT EXPIRY DATE AND PUT IN CELL
'I have tried reading up on extracting data from li elements, parent and child elements but struggling
For Each itemEle In objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top-section-list")
data = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("li")(0).innerText


'increment our row counter, so the next result goes below
y = y + 1

'repeat times cells have car regs in
'Next
'take next car reg and do the same as above until there are no cells in rows with a car reg
Next
Range("A3").Value = data


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'close the browser
objIE.Quit

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'exit our SearchBot subroutine and start new row for new website data
End Sub
```

I am a fraud investigator trying to teach myself VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items you want are in `strong` (**bold**) tags and are the first two on the page so you can use faster css selector of `strong` and do

```
Dim items As Object, i As Long, taxInfo As String, motInfo As String
Set items = ie.document.querySelectorAll("strong")
taxInfo = items.item(0).innerText
motInfo = items.item(1).innerText
```

for just the dates do:

```
taxInfo = Replace$(items.item(0).innerText,"Tax due: ",vbNullString)
motInfo = Replace$(items.item(1).innerText,"Expires: ",vbNullString)
```

Here is something similar using css selectors, which modern webpages are optimized for, so faster. The # is an id selector. I used a timed wait to ensure search box is present for entering registration. There is a rudimentary check in case vehicle not found.

```
Option Explicit   
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub CheckTax()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, searchBox As Object, t As Date, ws As Worksheet
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 20
    Dim inputValues(), i As Long

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT & DATA RESULTS")
    inputValues = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("F3:F5").Value) '<=change range here for range containing values to lookup
    With ie
        .Visible = True

        For i = LBound(inputValues) To UBound(inputValues)
            .Navigate2 "https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/"

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            t = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set searchBox = .document.querySelector("#Vrm")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While searchBox Is Nothing

            If searchBox Is Nothing Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                searchBox.Focus
                searchBox.Value = inputValues(i)
            End If

            .document.querySelector(".button").Click

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            If .document.querySelectorAll("h3").Length > 0 Then
                ws.Cells(i + 2, "G") = "Vehicle details could not be found"
                ws.Cells(i + 2, "H") = "Vehicle details could not be found"
            Else
                t = Timer
                Do
                    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
                Loop While ie.document.querySelectorAll("#Correct_True").Length = 0

                ie.document.querySelector("#Correct_True").Click
                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                .document.querySelector(".button").Click

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

                Dim items As Object, taxInfo As String, motInfo As String
                t = Timer
                Do
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set items = ie.document.querySelectorAll("strong")
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
                Loop While items.Length = 0

                'taxInfo = items.item(0).innerText
                'motInfo = items.item(1).innerText

                'Debug.Print taxInfo, motInfo

                taxInfo = Replace$(items.item(0).innerText, "Tax due: ", vbNullString)
                motInfo = Replace$(items.item(1).innerText, "Expires: ", vbNullString)

                ws.Cells(i + 2, "G") = taxInfo
                ws.Cells(i + 2, "H") = motInfo
            End If
            Set searchBox = Nothing: Set items = Nothing
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: A loop can easily be added but I am not sure if you are looping reg numbers in the sheet or selecting from a single changing cell value and running multiple times.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try this later. Hugs to ya

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I will be looping through the sheet and checking each a list of car registrations. would putting Next do the trick? thank you.

Comment: p.s is there some good material to read for using a css selector?

Comment: Thanks QHarr, I will try that, you have been very helpful. I have had a profile for some time but new to using this site properly, how do I vote you up? it says I don't have enough points. thanks.

Comment: hi QHarr, I have tried it but cant seem to get the loop to work until the cell is empty, the code so far works by inputting the first cell data in to the webpage and it does pickup the dates - thanks to you and your help, the next bit I am struggling with is the loop, I have done some research and read a lot of webpages but nothing seems specific enough for the loop I want. thanks for your time.

Comment: hiya - so my code picks up all search strings from the range F3:F5. Does it successfully complete those two searches for you?

Comment: The search values are put in an array and then accessed from the array in a loop i.e.  searchBox.Value = inputValues(i)

Comment: hi again, I am sorry, I am having some issues with this loop, I want to loop through the column of registrations until there are none and for each reg have the tax and mot date put to the right of it.

Comment: this is the current code, I tried your code but had to simplify back to what I had as I have been doing this for only a few months now, sorry but thank you. are you able to use my code and maybe just add the loop I need with the error handling bit you raised? thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure. But consider accepting @Matteo's answer if you are using it.

Comment: Do you have an xlsx with some sample data in it (doesn't have to be real registration) - just the layout of data you want to use for the search and example of where expected return values would go.

Comment: Hey, I did thi k of loading the sheet but could t see how to on here sorry noon troubles. In column x from row 3 down my registrations are G780bbk (mine) v974gbp. The 2 columns to the right of the registrations will be where the dates go. Sorry I hope this helps. P. S I have tried matts way and it helps I just can't loop. Thanks again

Comment: It's ok. So what failed when running mine? It should loop the range

Comment: Hey ya, sorry, on your one it had problems with the web pages and opening them, I couldnt get past that bit sorry to say. Appreciate your time if there is anything I can do for you let me know.

Comment: what was the problem? Can you give me a way to recreate the problem? You can https://pastebin.com/ code I can use to recreate the problem. Thing I overdid the use of the word problem there!

Comment: hi Qharr I am sorry, I am really stuck I jhave taken bits of yours and matteos code to keep my simple - because I want to keep with as much of my code as possible as I am new to all of this and need to keep it simple for me, I am lost in your code (very apt but its my failing for not knowing enough). what might be best is now I have this problem sorted for taken the right htlm elements I might post for the loop - could I add you to that so you can see the code I have for that as I have had to modify my sheet a little? thank you

Comment: I posted a link underneath your new question. If you aren’t comfortable with looping an array just look at the range definition for column x. Instead of using transpose, set that range to a variable and For Each over the cells in that range. Then access the value in each cell your are looping over

Comment: hi qharr, I am going to learn the things you advised and see if I can sort this looping issue out I have. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of this webpage is pretty simple, there is only one element with `class` = `status-bar` and inside this, the two information you look for are inside a tag of type `strong`.

So, without need to loop, you can simply do this (right after where you wrote 'The above works'):

```
'TAX EXPIRY DATE:
TaxExpiryDate = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
'MOT EXPIRY DATE:
MotExpiryDate = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(1).innerText
```

Then you can put the variables `TaxExpiryDate` and `MotExpiryDate` where you wish (e.g. `Range("A1").Value = TaxExpiryDate`).

The variable itself contains the plain content of the `<strong>` tag:

```
Tax due:
01 July 2019
```

If you only want to get the date, you can `Split()` using the `vbNewLine` as a delimiter and just get the second part of the split:

```
'IN TWO LINES FOR BETTER CODE READIBILITY:
TaxExpiryDate = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
TaxExpiryDate = Split(TaxExpiryDate, vbNewLine)(1)

'IN ONE LINE FOR SHORTER CODE:
TaxExpiryDate = Split(objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText, vbNewLine)(1)
```

Comment: hi matteo, that was really helpful and got me the result I wanted. please may you help me move to the next rows vehicle regs until its blank? thank you for your time. Gaz

Comment: hi matteo, please may you help me with the code for looping through the rows until they are empty, iam having some real issues with that bit. thanks again.